# How to fix node.js vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js

Below are the vulnerabilities that I get:

-You can see that all vulnerabilities depend on `node-fetch  <=2.6.6` When I look upon how to fix it on GitHub it says that versions lower than 2.6.1 need to be updated. Yet my version is 2.6.6 and I'm still getting a vulnerability message. Are there any possible ways of fixing this? Another issue is that I can't seem to find it in `package-lock.json` folder either and I'm unable to update/change it manually. I've tried uninstalling the entire package-lock.json and reinstalling it, and I'm still stuck with this vulnerability message. Thanks to anyone who can help!

````
Severity: high
The `size` option isn't honored after following a redirect in node-fetch - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-w7rc-rwvf-8q5r
node-fetch is vulnerable to Exposure of Sensitive Information to an Unauthorized Actor - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r683-j2x4-v87g
No fix available
node_modules/isomorphic-fetch/node_modules/node-fetch
  Depends on vulnerable versions of node-fetch
  node_modules/isomorphic-fetch
    fbjs  0.7.0 - 1.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of isomorphic-fetch
    node_modules/fbjs
      fbemitter  2.0.3 - 3.0.0-alpha.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
      node_modules/fbemitter
        expo  >=14.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of fbemitter
        node_modules/expo
        Depends on vulnerable versions of fbemitter
        node_modules/expo-updates```
````

Comment: The issue is fixed with node-fetch@2.6.7, you can use `npm i node-fetch@2.6.7 and all should fall into place. There have been a bunch of projects I had to update since we are not running node-fetch 3 yet.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is still there for me. I uninstalled node.js and vscode completely, deleted all my projects and I'm still getting vulnerabilities. Do you know if this is normal? I don't even have a project/folder open, I only have the terminal open and when I type ```npm audit``` I'm still getting the same vulnerabilities.

Comment: Fixed the issue, I had something installed on my Local Disk which was causing the issue, I've uninstalled it and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Will an `npm audit fix` handle it? Sometime I just reset everything by delete `node_modules` folder and package-lock.json file and run `npm i`